# How to send an image from a Python process to a Flask app with POST request

Tags: python, post, flask, request

I have

- *takePhoto.py* : a Python script that takes a picture from the webcam
- *app.py* a Flask app that handles POST request

How can I send the image taken from *takePhoto.py* to the Flask app with a POST request?

**takePhoto.py**

```
import cv2 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
r, f = cap.read()

if r == True: 
    cv2.imwrite("cheese.jpg", f)
    # ---> Here I have the image and I want to send it to the Flask app

cap.release()
```

**app.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
IMAGE_FOLDER = os.path.join('static', 'photos')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = IMAGE_FOLDER


@app.route('/')
def show_index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/uploadPicture', methods=['POST'])
def uploadPicture():
    print("uploadPicture function triggered")
    file = request.files['image']
    complete_file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename)
    file.save(complete_file_path)
    return render_template("gallery.html", current_image = complete_file_path )

if __name__ == ("__main__"):
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you describe, you are running two processing. they do different job but you want it work together. so you have to use `IPC` or something like `queue` or `redis` to communicate each other. In here, you can use `PUB/SUB` pattern, but flask doesn't support it by default. Here are something dos you can check.

[Migurel's Blog](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask)

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504023/how-to-communicate-between-processes-while-theyre-running)